# [ODBC SQL Server driver][DBMSLPCN]SSL Security error

Tags: sql-server, ssl, visual-c++, odbc, windows-server-2012-r2

I am getting Error
**"[microsoft][ODBC SQL Server driver][DBMSLPCN]SSL Security error"**
while connecting throught **SQLDriverConnect**() using 
connection string **"DRIVER=SQLServer;SERVER=localhost\XXXSQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=xxxDB;UID=xxxxxx;PWD=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=No"**;

It was working earlier before re-installing
SQL Server 2014.
But able connect using SQLCMD and SQL Server management studio.

Thanks for your kind help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are using the legacy SQL Server ODBC driver, which is provided with Windows for backwards compatibility. Try using either the SQL Server Native Client or ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server. Those support TLS 1.2.

Comment: But nothing we have changed, just did re install SQL Server 2014.  This issue happens to particular PC(having ServerOS).

Comment: This happens after disabling TLS1.0, SSL 2.0 client.  Could you guess? @Dan Guzman.